# Google Script - skip row

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have a form that's automatically filling in rows on Google Sheets, and I want to fill in additional cells as soon as a new row gets entered. However this is also triggering the Header row- how do I skip the first row?

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
var data_len = data.length;
for(var i=1; i<data_len; i++) {
  if(data[i][0] != "") {
    s.getRange(i+1,2).setValue("ready");
```

(A new row is "ready," otherwise empty rows remain "").